# how to display markdown on a webpage

Tags: c#, razor, markdown

I have the following code that allows me to `GET` the content of a markdown file using `github api` in a razor project:

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using MarkdownSharp;
@page "/"

<div>
    @content
</div>


@code{

    public string content { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        const string url = "https://api.github.com/repos/angrymonkeydocs/amd-css/contents/README.md";
        HttpClient client = new();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("AngryMonkeyDocs", "1"));
        string responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);
        string jsonContent = json["content"];
        string content = Base64Decode(jsonContent);
        
    }

    private static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
    {
        var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }
}
```

In its current form, the string is posted as it is:
[image]

How can I make it so that I would actually have the `content` posted on my webpage as a markup i.e: https://github.com/angrymonkeydocs/amd-css#readme

Comment: You need a markdown parser to translate it to html.

Comment: Yeah. Markdig is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need add this package to project https://github.com/xoofx/markdig
then you can use custom tag helper like this:

```
public class MarkdownTagHelper: TagHelper 
{
  public override async Task ProcessAsync( 
  TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) 
 {
     TagHelperContent markdownRazorContent = await 
     output.GetChildContentAsync(NullHtmlEncoder.Default); 
     string markdown = 
     markdownRazorContent.GetContent(NullHtmlEncoder.Default); 
     string html = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(markdown); 
     output.Content.SetHtmlContent(html); 
     output.TagName = null; 
 }
}
```

this is razor page with `markdown` tag helper

```
<markdown>
## This is a markdown title

This is a markdown list:
* Item 1
* Item 2
<div>
it can have html tag
</div>
</markdown>
```

when this razor page render, `<markdown>` content covert to html tags.